# Named virtual host on Debian Squeeze only serves the default host

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I am trying to setup my own virtual host on Debian Squeeze and I think I have done the setup as per the documentation and have gone through a number of questions and answers. Everything seems to suggest I have done everything right. However, I see that it always serves only the default site. As per another related question I checked my setup as follows:

```
$ (source /etc/apache2/envvars && /usr/sbin/apache2 -S)
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server hms01san.lan (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost hms01san.lan (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)

Syntax OK
```

I tried changing the '*:80' in the NameVirtualHost as well as the VirtualHost entries to a simple '*', but get the same issue.

Would appreciate any help in getting this fixed.

Update: I get this issue only when using the external DNS redirect of my domain setting, works fine when I setup the host name locally in my /etc/hosts.

Comment: Please provide output of: `cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf; for i in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*; do echo "=== $i ==="; cat "$i"; done`. What is the result of DNS query for the domain in question using external DNS?
What do you add to /etc/hosts?

Comment: It's all resolved now. Thanks for taking a look, [0xFF](http://serverfault.com/users/98592/0xff). The issue was with the settings of my domain. I had to update the DNS settings of my domain instead of the http redirect that I had setup.